# The property 'xxx' on entity type 'xxx' cannot be marked as nullable/optional because the type of the property is 'short' which is not a nullable type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, migration

I have an entity with `short` data type and I want another entity to have a null-able relationship with this table. After executing Add-Migration I get the error in mentioned in Title of this question.
Isn't it possible to have short as null-able property?

Comment: Use `short?` instead. `short` can't be null, but `short?`can.

Comment: @Magnetron Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing `short` to `short?` the error is gone.